# Cannot mount or move Virtual Hard Disk .vhdx file

Tags: virtual-machine, mount, windows-10, hyper-v

I created a .vhdx file using `disk2vhd` from sysinternals, but I'm unable to use it. The virtual machine in Hyper-V won't start.

I can't mount it either. I t gives me the following error even though I have full control permissions.

> Couldn't mount File
>   You don't have permission to mount the file.

When I try to move it, I get the error :

> The action can't be completed because the file is open in System.

I checked that Hyper-V does not use it. I even deleted the virtual machine to be sure it is not used by Hyper-V.

What could I try else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tool from Sysinternals is quite old now. You could check out the official tool from Microsoft. [Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42497). It will convert other VM's and physical disks to Hyper-V readable drives.

Comment: The problem was disk2vhd. I made a full backup and restored it to the virtual machine. This worked.