# How to convert Windows 8.1 live machine to bootable .vhd and run it in VirtualBox?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, virtualbox, vhd, disk2vhd

I tried converting my PC using `disk2vhd` several times with no success. I check all partitions including hidden system partitions and create single `.vhd` file from it. I did it before with Windows XP and Windows 7 and both boots in Virtual Box without problems.

For Windows 8.1 I always get `No bootable medium found` when trying to boot the VHD.

Are there any special steps to take in either creating VHD or attaching it to VirtualBox to make the system boot? I need it for an emergency backup before I wipe up the system and upgrade to Windows 10.

Comment: Please see my answer [here](http://superuser.com/questions/955166/cannot-mount-or-move-virtual-hard-disk-vhdx-file/955719#955719) on a similar question.

Comment: Thanks @MrStatic, I'll try this today. But will this run on VirtualBox? I have Home version of Windows unfortunately which will not let me run Hyper-V as far as I know.

Comment: Honestly not sure, but I know the disk2vhd is getting long in the tooth and having issues for people.